# Consecutive Green Days

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to find the number of consecutive green closing prices from a dataframe before a certain date.

Input:

```
  Ticker      Date  Close
0   AAPL  20200501    1.5
1   AAPL  20200502    1.2
2   AAPL  20200503    1.3
3   AAPL  20200504    1.3
4   AAPL  20200505    1.4
5   AAPL  20200506    1.5
```

In this example I would want to know the consecutive closing prices that were higher than the previous day's closing prices on 20200507

Desired output:

```
2
```

Here is the code for the example dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker': ['AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL', 'AAPL'],
                'Date': [20200501, 20200502, 20200503, 20200504, 20200505, 20200506],
               'Close': [1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]})
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Quang Hoang Answer will work if you want to get the length of the longest streak.
If you instead want the length of the current streak of consecutive days the following will work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Close' : [1.5, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]})

streaks = (df['Close'].diff() <= 0).cumsum()
res = sum(streaks == streaks.iloc[-1]) - 1
```

**Edit:**
If you have rows with dates after `20200507` you can adapt like this:

```
df_subview = df[df['Date'] < 20200507]
```

**Edit2:**
Why `df['Close'].diff() <= 0` instead of `df['Close'].diff() > 0`?

This is what we want to arvieve:

```
>>> streaks
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
```

There are 3 Streaks here at play, the first ending after the 1. day, the second ending after the third day (index 2-3) and the last streak going all the way to the end.

To archieve this we need some number that goes up every time a streak is lost. We can use `.cumsum` on an array of `0s` and `1s` to get this behaviour. Everytime a streak is lost the date should be marked as a `1`.

How do we test if a streak is **broken**? By doing the opposite of `df['Close'].diff() > 0`, i.e. `df['Close'].diff() <= 0`. That produces the following result:

```
>>> df['Close'].diff() <= 0
0    False
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: Close, dtype: bool
```

Because internally `True` is a `1` and `False` a `0` we already have the required Array of Zeros and Ones.

```
>>> (df['Close'].diff() <= 0).astype(int)
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
Name: Close, dtype: int64
```

Now we can apply `.cumsum` and get the length of the last streak. Because `True` is already treated as a `1` we can omit the step `.astype(int)` and directly call `(df['Close'].diff() <= 0).cumsum()`.

Comment: Thank you, this works great!!
Could you meaby tell me if there is a way to add a criteria to this? for example only if the closing price is 3% or more above the previous price?

Comment: Yes there is. Use `streaks = (df['Close'].pct_change() <= 0.03).cumsum()`. You can alter streaks in any way you like so that whenever a streak is broken a `True` is produced. (Which then causes `.cumsum` to go one up stopping the streak)

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I will mess around with this. One last question, what is the reason you use  "<= 0.03" instead of ">=0.03"? changing this does not seem to produce the desired result, but it seems odd to me

Comment: I added that explanation for the case `.diff() <= 0`. It's the same logic for `pct_change() <= 0.03`.

Comment: Great explanation man, I wish I could give you 20 upvotes. Thanks a lot your time!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1['Close'].diff().gt(0)[::-1].cumprod().sum()
```

out：

```
2
```